# How to "install" an icon on iphone's springboard that when pressed shows a local html

Tags: ios, html

I made an hybrid app that downloads a zip from my server, unzips it and stores the content on my iPad and then shows the html content on a UIWebView.

I'm interested to know how to make it download the content and store it, and then my app closes and you can see an icon installed on springboard which can be clicked to open the content I just saved on safari as a webapp.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: impossible. Your are in iOS where every App has its Sandbox, so your unzipped data is only available to your app and not to Safari for security reasons.

Comment: I´ve seen this behaviour in Yooba app that`s why I know it's possible